# How to split image to objects ("islands") using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjywB.png). It is made of 3 white "islands" on black background. I want to split this image into thouse islands. Is there a function in opencv or in numpy that does something like that? I have my implementation of that function. It works with 2d bool numpy arrays:

```
def get_island(img, x, y):
    island = numpy.zeros_like(img, dtype=bool)
    neibourghood = [(0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0)]
    island[x, y] = True
    img[x, y] = False
    dots = [(x, y),]
    while len(dots) > 0:
        dots2 = dots
        dots = []
        for x, y in dots2:
            for xs, ys in neibourghood:
                x2, y2 = x + xs, y + ys
                if 0 <= x2 < img.shape[0] and 0 <= y2 < img.shape[1]:
                    if img[x2, y2]:
                        img[x2, y2] = False
                        island[x2, y2] = True
                        dots.append((x2, y2),)
    return island


def get_islands(img:numpy.ndarray) -> list: # <- that function
    img = numpy.copy(img)
    islands = []
    while 1:
        xa, ya = numpy.where(img)
        if xa.shape[0] == 0: break
        x, y = xa[0], ya[0]
        islands.append(get_island(img, x, y))
    return islands
```

Result will be list([[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu8zS.png), [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x79Qn.png), [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99auU.png)])

But it is slow. I want to find a faster way to do that.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: findContours or connected components labeling. described in opencv's docs, the tutorials section.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz , thanks.

Comment: if you want to stick with your code, give `numba` a look.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz , I know about numba. You can `jit` only `get_island` function. And for it to work you need to put out of that function `island = numpy.zeros_like(img, dtype=bool)` line because numba can't compile it. But `cv2.connectedComponents` is a ready solution. Why don't you like it? And also my function have a problem which opencv does not have. When there is a lot of islands it produses many images (as many as islands) and uses a lot of memory. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz , if I use numba, I will have to install it to run the program when it's finished. I don't want to use many dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is `cv2.connectedComponents` function in opencv. It does what I need.

```
def get_islands(img):
    n, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img.astype('uint8'))
    islands = [labels == i for i in range(1, n)]
    return islands
```